# Problems with using Customized Bulma with Flask

Tags: flask, bulma, node-sass

I keep getting the error "GET /css/mystyles.css HTTP/1.1" 404 - when I try to run my Flask project with a customized Bulma.
How I'm linking the stylesheet in index.html:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/mystyles.css">
```

[directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Z35h.png)

This is the Bulma documentation I followed to set up a customized Bulma: https://bulma.io/documentation/customize/with-node-sass/

I've tried moving the css folder into the templates folder, but it doesn't do anything.

The project does work if I'm using just Bulma without any customizations by just linking the Bulma CSS file like in this documentation: https://bulma.io/documentation/overview/start/

```
<link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bulma@0.9.4/css/bulma.min.css"
    />
```

Comment: If your css files are stored within your static directory then the following should work `<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='css/mystyles.css’) }}”>`. The flask tutorial has a section on static files at https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/tutorial/static/.